# JQuery .parent click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, this, parent

The use of "this" and ".parent()" in jquery gets a bit confusing when it goes past simple divs or datatables. I have a table with the following structure: (I can't rename any of the classes or id)

```
<table class="table1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <div class="detail">
                <table>
                     <thead></thead>
                     <tbody>
                         <tr>
                            <td>
                                <img class="picture_open" src="../location">
</td></tr></tbody></table></div></tr></tbody></table>
```

What I'm trying to do is have a click function on that img which will be able to grab the full RowElement.

What I have now:

```
$(".table1 tbody tr td img.picture_open").live('click', function () {
    var overallTable = jQuery(this).parent("table").dataTable();
    console.log("overallTable: " + overallTable);
    var elementRow = this.parentNode.parentNode;
    console.log("elementRow: " + elementRow);

    var rowData = overallTable.fnGetData( elementRow );
    console.log("rowData: " + rowData);
    if ( this.src.match('img_name') )
    {
        //kills the table that was created if that row is opened
    }
    else
    {
        //runs ajax call to create another table since row is NOT opened
    }
} );
```

However the code I have above prints out this:
    overallTable: [object Object]
    elementRow: [object HTMLTableRowElement]
    TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'oSettings.aoData')

In my problem is the $(this) incorrect? (Not getting the img with class "picture_open")
Or is my  overallTable variable set up incorrectly with the .parent()?
Or is it my elementRow variable set up improperly with the parentNode?
Any help to clarify my errors would be amazing.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you want to use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) instead of `.parent()`

Comment: What you're trying to do is very unclear.  `this` will be the img element, and you are already getting the row with `.parentNode.parentNode`

Comment: @Blazemonger: I think you are right. After reading the documentation on .closest(), I think it is a better fit than .parent()

Comment: @ExplosionPills: I am using OverallTable to find the <table> that has no class. elementRow finds the overall row I need. Then rowData gets the data from that row so that I can access variables in it later. for ex) rowData.date which can be passed into the ajax call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parent()` in jQuery will parse only one level up the DOM, you should use `.parents()/.closest()`. This will fix your issue.

**NOTE:** `.live()` is turned into `.on()` in latest jQuery versions. Better to use `.on()/.click()`

Comment: i tried: var overallTable = $(this).parents("table").dataTable(); 
and I get:
overallTable: [object Object]
elementRow: [object HTMLTableRowElement]
then the same error
is there a way where I can see what is being grabbed?Not just that it is an object?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$('.table1').on('click', '.picture_open', function(ev) {
    this // is .picture_open element
    ev.target // is .picture_open element
    ev.delegateTarget // is .table1 element

    var $row = $(ev.delegateTarget).find('.detail tr').first();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`parent()` in jQuery only moves one level up the DOM, so what you probably want there is `parents('table')`. This should fix your overallTable issue.

Answer (score 0):

in jQuery, [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) only goes up the DOM once. What you should be using it [.parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) to look up the DOM until it finds `table`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.closest('table')` to find the closest table

Similary to find the element row

```
var elementRow = $(this).closest('tr');
```